# Powershell Schedule on SBS 2011 won't send e-mail

Tags: windows, powershell, sendmail, schedule

I've created a Powershell script which I'm trying to run as a scheduled task. If I run the script within Powershell it runs fine and sends an e-mail. However if I run it as a scheduled task it looks like it runs and doesn't send an e-mail yet gives 0x0 on the schedule code. I have put in a sleep of 10 seconds after the e-mail function too.
I have set the same script up on my work windows 7 machine as a scheduled task and it runs fine and sends an e-mail as expected and also on my windows 8 home machine.

The script checks for files in a folder, if any files exist it checks the age of the oldest files and if the file is over 60 minutes old sends an e-mail alert, otherwise it does nothing and exits.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
$FilePath = "C:\path1\"
$age = 60

function send-email {
$EmailFrom = "email@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "email@email.co.uk" 
$Subject = "File Alert" 
$Body = "Check the file folder, files are over 60 minutes old. File = " + "$filepath" + "$OldestFile" +" "+ "Minutes = " + "$MinutesTrunc"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}

$fileExistence = test-path ($FilePath + "*")
if ($fileExistence -eq $false)
{ 
exit
}
else
{
#continue
}

$OldestFile = Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -first 1
$StartDate=$OldestFile.LastWriteTime
$EndDate=get-date

$TimeDiff = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
$Minutes = $TimeDiff.totalminutes
$MinutesTrunc = [MATH]::Truncate($Minutes)

if ($Minutes -ge $age)
{
send-email
start-sleep -s 10
}
else
{
exit
}
```

Comment: I have been trying so many different things to get this to work and the answer was simple.
In the arguments on the scheduled task I had:

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass 'C:\MyPath\File.ps1' 

This worked fine on the other machines but wasn't working on the sbs machine for whatever reason. Before the path I put an & symbol, so it became 

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass &'C:\MyPath\File.ps1'

Tested and this works fine!

Comment: -exec bypass -file 'c:\mypathfile.ps1' would probably have worked just fine. You might want to put your solution as answer.

Comment: It didn't work on the sbs machine unless I Put the & symbol, even with -file, my other two machines it ran fine without the &. Strange. I will put it as the answer once the time allows me to :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the argument from

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass 'C:\MyPath\File.ps1'

to

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass &'C:\MyPath\File.ps1' (note the &) worked for some reason.